# using windows authentication in io.restassured api testing

Tags: java, rest-assured

we are trying to test an api where it uses Windows authentication. I'm using rest-assured package to test api's. Any suggestion how to assign windows logged in user to api request header?

Comment: I also would like to find this. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Have rewised my answer
So, currently it's quite hard to do, because you need to configure HTTPClient for REST Assured, but it supports only deprecated `AbstractHttpClient`. Here is my implementation. but i have no ability to test it...

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import org.apache.http.annotation.Contract;
import org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadingBehavior;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScheme;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeFactory;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeProvider;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.config.AuthSchemes;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicSchemeFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.DigestSchemeFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.win.WindowsCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.win.WindowsNegotiateScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static io.restassured.config.HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig;
import static java.net.HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;

public class WinHttpClientTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        @Contract(threading = ThreadingBehavior.IMMUTABLE)
        class WindowsNTLMSchemeFactory implements AuthSchemeProvider, AuthSchemeFactory {

            private final String servicePrincipalName;

            public WindowsNTLMSchemeFactory(final String servicePrincipalName) {
                super();
                this.servicePrincipalName = servicePrincipalName;
            }

            @Override
            public AuthScheme create(final HttpContext context) {
                return new WindowsNegotiateScheme(AuthSchemes.NTLM, servicePrincipalName);
            }

            @Override
            public AuthScheme newInstance(HttpParams params) {
                return new WindowsNegotiateScheme(AuthSchemes.NTLM, null) ;
            }
        }

        @Contract(threading = ThreadingBehavior.IMMUTABLE)
        class WindowsNegotiateSchemeFactory implements AuthSchemeProvider, AuthSchemeFactory {

            private final String servicePrincipalName;

            public WindowsNegotiateSchemeFactory(final String servicePrincipalName) {
                super();
                this.servicePrincipalName = servicePrincipalName;
            }

            @Override
            public AuthScheme create(final HttpContext context) {
                return new WindowsNegotiateScheme(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, servicePrincipalName);
            }

            @Override
            public AuthScheme newInstance(HttpParams params) {
                return new WindowsNegotiateScheme(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, null);
            }
        }

        AuthSchemeRegistry authSceme = new AuthSchemeRegistry();
        authSceme.register(AuthSchemes.BASIC, new BasicSchemeFactory());
        authSceme.register(AuthSchemes.DIGEST, new DigestSchemeFactory());
        authSceme.register(AuthSchemes.NTLM, new WindowsNTLMSchemeFactory(null));
        authSceme.register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, new WindowsNegotiateSchemeFactory(null));

        final CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new WindowsCredentialsProvider(new SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider());
        AbstractHttpClient httpClient = new SystemDefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.setAuthSchemes(authSceme);
        httpClient.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

        RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().httpClient(httpClientConfig().httpClientFactory(() -> httpClient));
        given()
                .log().all()
                .when()
                .get("http://httpbin.org/get")
                .then()
                .log().all()
                .statusCode(HTTP_OK);
    }

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with authentication. The answer will only set information in header.

Comment: @Piazzolla the question was: how to assign windows logged in user to api request header? What exactly do you want?

Comment: yes that is the last part of the question but at least the title and questions include "windows authentication" and information about which user it is is not authentication only information. I can see that I might be a bit hard on your answer.

Comment: Isn't it enough to pass user and password as basic auth header? like `given().auth().basic("username", "password")`

Comment: Will do! (Looks promising)

Comment: We did not get it to work unfortunetly. Could of course be something with our setup. (I removed my down vote). Thank you for your try!

Comment: Could you share executable example?